# Sorting mixed String-Int Strings numerically as the primary order, then alphabetically in swift

Tags: swift, sorting

For a String which have both String and Int values (one of each) is it possible to do simple sort that will give the items ordered in numerical order as the primary order and alphabetical as the secondary order

```
var nameArray = ["Dave7", "Bob8", "Cathy9", "Henry10", "Susan10", "Pat11", "Steve12", "Dan12", "Ken1", "Sean2", "Howard3", "Dixie3", "Newman5", "Billy6"]

var sortedNameArray = nameArray.sort { $0.compare($1, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending }

print(sortedNameArray)  // gives the following:
```

Don't want this -> `["Billy6", "Bob8", "Cathy9", "Dan12", "Dave7", "Dixie3", "Henry10", "Howard3", "Ken1", "Newman5", "Pat11", "Sean2", "Steve12", "Susan10"]`

Even though `.NumericSearch` was used the result is alphabetical.

I was able to get the desired result using a custom binary tree.  Which gives the results:

```
Ken1 Sean2 Dixie3 Howard3 Newman5 Billy6 Dave7 Bob8 Cathy9 Henry10 Susan10 Pat11 Dan12 Steve12
```

But is there a simpler solution?

```
extension String {

    var integerValue: Int? {
        return Int(self)
    }
}

func extractValueFromString(theString:String)->Int{

    var catNumber: [Character] = []

     //print("theString \(theString)")

    for character in theString.characters{

        var characterString = String(character)

        if var value = characterString.integerValue { //if we don't check program crashes


            //if numberSet.contains(Int(String(character))!) { //another way to check but redundant here

                catNumber.append(character)
               //print(catNumber)
           // }
        }
    }

    let numberString = String(catNumber)

    return Int(numberString)!
}




class Node{

    //nodes now only arrange strings
    var data = ""
    var value = Int()
    var left:Node?;
    var right:Node?;
    deinit {
        //print("deleting \(data)")
       // print("node  deleted")
    }


    init(data:String){
        self.data = data;

        //print(data)
    }

}


class binaryTreeSort{

    var root:Node?

    init(){

    }

    deinit {

        //print("tree  deleted")
    }

    func getRoot()->Node{

        return root!

    }



    func insertNewValue(data:String){

        let newNode = Node(data:data)

        var node:Node? = root

        if (node == nil){
            root = newNode

        }


        while (node != nil) {

            let currentValue = node?.data


            if currentValue == ""{

                node?.data = data
                return
            }

            if currentValue == data {
                //we don't want duplicates.
                return
            }
            if extractValueFromString(currentValue!) <  extractValueFromString(data) {

                if (node!.right != nil) {
                    node = node!.right
                    //print("Going Right at data \(node!.data)")

                }else{
                    node!.right = newNode
                    //print("Going New Right at data \(node!.data)")
                    return
                }
            }else if extractValueFromString(currentValue!) ==  extractValueFromString(data){

                if  currentValue < data {

                    if (node!.right != nil) {
                        node = node!.right
                        //print("Going Right at data \(node!.data)")

                    }else{
                        node!.right = newNode
                        //print("Going New Right at data \(node!.data)")
                        return
                    }



                }else{


                    if (node!.left != nil) {
                        //print("Going Left at data \(node!.data)")
                        node = node!.left
                    }else{
                        node!.left = newNode
                        //print("Going New Left at data \(node!.data)")
                        return
                    }


                }

            }
            else{
                if (node!.left != nil) {
                    //print("Going Left at data \(node!.data)")
                    node = node!.left
                }else{
                    node!.left = newNode
                    //print("Going New Left at data \(node!.data)")
                    return
                }
            }
        }


    }

    func inorderPrint(baseNode:Node){

        if(baseNode.left != nil)
        {
            inorderPrint(baseNode.left!);
            //print("  \(baseNode.data)")
        }




      print("\(baseNode.data)")


        if(baseNode.right != nil)
        {

            inorderPrint(baseNode.right!)
            //print("    \(baseNode.data)")
        }



    }




    func reverseOrderPrint(baseNode:Node){


        if(baseNode.right != nil)
        {

            reverseOrderPrint(baseNode.right!)
            //print("    \(baseNode.data)")
        }



              print("\(baseNode.data)")



        if(baseNode.left != nil)
        {
            reverseOrderPrint(baseNode.left!);
            //print("  \(baseNode.data)")
        }


    }

}

    var myBinaryTreeSort:binaryTreeSort? = binaryTreeSort()

for item in nameArray{
    //print(item)

    myBinaryTreeSort!.insertNewValue(item)
}

myBinaryTreeSort!.inorderPrint(myBinaryTreeSort!.getRoot())
print("---------------")

myBinaryTreeSort!.reverseOrderPrint(myBinaryTreeSort!.getRoot())

myBinaryTreeSort = nil //delete the tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map to split the names into parts, sort to sort by number and name, and then map to restore the original:

```
func splitName(name:String) -> (String, Int) {
    if let range = name.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()) {
     return (name[name.startIndex..<range.startIndex], Int(name[range.startIndex..<name.endIndex])!)
   } else {
        return (name, 0)
    }
}

print(nameArray.map(splitName).sort({ lhs, rhs in
    if lhs.1 < rhs.1 {
        return true
    } else if lhs.1 > rhs.1 {
        return false
    } else {
        return lhs.0 < rhs.0
    }
}).map({ "\($0.0)\($0.1)" }))
```

Some other ways it could be done would be to maintain element 0 of the tuple as the full name (with numbers) and then the final map just becomes `map({ $0.0 })`  Depending on sizes, this may be more optimal than splitting the name each time it's compared.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array, you can sort with a custom closure.

For example:

```
  nameArray.sort({extractValueFromString($0) < extractValueFromString($1)})
```

Will get you close.  You just need to check if they are equal and return `$0 < $1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this, doing something similar to what @Lou-Franco alluded to:

```
func endInteger(word: String) -> Int {
    if let range = word.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()){
        let numberSubstring = word.substringFromIndex(range.startIndex)
        return Int(numberSubstring) ?? 0
    }
    return 0
}

let sortedArray = yourArray.sort{endInteger($1) > endInteger($0)}
```